# Can $\cos(x)$ be written as the difference of two increasing functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Can f(x)=cos(x) be written as the difference of two increasing functions on the open interval $(0,2\pi )$ ?

Comment: $\cos x =(2x+\cos x )-(2x)$.

Comment: Re Taylor series : $$\cos(x) = \left[1 + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^8}{8!} + \cdots\right] - \left[\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} + \cdots\right].$$

Comment: As a freebie: "A real valued function is of bounded variation iff. it is the difference of two increasing functions" and any (almost everywhere) continuously differentiable function (e.g. cosine) is of bounded variation (since they are absolutely continuous)

Comment: @FShrike Skip “almost everywhere.”  There is an easy example of a differentiable function whose derivative is continuous at all but one point, but that function does not have bounded variation.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Ok, thank you for the note